# JPQL / Criteria API Order By MAX OneToMany association

Tags: sql-order-by, one-to-many, jpql, criteria-api

I have the following data model: Customer with OneToMany relationship to Order.

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
    ...

    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Order> orders;

    ...
}


@Entity
public class Order{
    ...
    private Long id;

    private Date orderDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    ...
}
```

**I want to list top 10 Customers based on latest orderDate.** So, a customer who has placed an order on the most recent date should appear on top of the list and so on.

Is it possible to do this using a single JPQL or Criteria API?

Comment: Just to mention: I ended up with using JPA's native SQL approach to solve this problem. Not sure if that's best approach however given the situation it's definitely a viable one.

Answer (score 0):

In HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select Customer c JOIN c.orders order ORDER BY order.orderDate DESC")
query.setMaxResults(10);
```

And some suggestions about what you write and your code:

- **Avoid EAGER**. Every *ToOne relationship in JPA do an EAGER fetching. Change the fetchType to LAZY if is this possible.
- **Native query only in the last case**. In specific cases they are very useful. But, to do a simple query, you you will gain limitations if you want to work with more than one database at once (common scenario for integration tests). For example, to make this simple query that limits the amount of information, each database uses a different way to accomplish this (`limit`, `rownum`, `top`, etc.). Using HQL / Criteria, you do not have to worry about this.